# Read Wicket Property from Spring servicelayer

Tags: java, spring, properties, wicket

I'm writing a service to export a bunch of settings to a file. Naturally I want to reuse the already existing labels. We are dealing with a Spring+Wicket-Setup.
The labels are defined in a properties-file.

How can I access the properties?

I tried using `StringResourceModels`, but `MissingResourceException` was thrown all the time. I tried loading the properties *by hand* like

```
InputStream iStream;
iStream = MySettingsPage.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MySettingsPage.properties");
if (iStream != null) {
  prop.load(iStream);
}
```

But the `InputStream` is `null`, so no properties are loaded.

I haven't found anything about accessing Wicket properties from a Spring-Service.

Even though I know one should not entangle Spring services with Wicket classes, I'm willing to accept the consequences if there is no other way. Furthermore I'd like to avoid loading the properties *by hand* because they are already cached.

Comment: Why aren't you using the Wicket way of getting the properties? do you write the properties files at runtime? How?

Comment: I'd think using the StringResourceModel would be the Wicket way, but since I don't have an instance of the corresponding component I can't use StringResourceModel as I would do in the component itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iStream = MySettingsPage.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MySettingsPage.properties");
```

will try to load the file from the root of the classpath. I have the feeling that this file is next to MySettingsPage.class, i.e. it is in a package like `com.example.myproduct`. In that case use:

```
iStream = MySettingsPage.class.getResourceAsStream("MySettingsPage.properties");
```